# Set factor order in MultiBarChart with NVD3 rCharts

Tags: r, rcharts

I want to change the order of the bars in the following graph:

```
library(rCharts)
effectiveness <- structure(list(Ranking = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Bottom", 
"Bellow Average", "Average", "Above Average", "Top"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), Probability = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.08, 0.02, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.01, 0.04, 0.15, 0.7, 
0.1), data = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("none", 
"little", "some", "lots"), class = c("ordered", "factor"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .Names = c("Ranking", "Probability", "data"), class = "data.frame")

library(rCharts)
n1 <- nPlot(Probability ~ data, group = 'Ranking', data = effectiveness[order(effectiveness$Ranking),], type = 'multiBarChart')
n1$chart(stacked = TRUE)
n1$yAxis( tickFormat = "#!d3.format('%')!#" )
n1$set(width = 1000)
n1$xAxis(axisLabel = "Data available")
n1
```

The order should be 'none' 'little' 'some'  'lots'.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402474/reorder-factor-in-multibarchart-with-nvd3-rcharts) is not working for me:

```
effectiveness$data <- as.numeric(effectiveness$data)
n1 <- nPlot(Probability ~ data, group = 'Ranking', data = effectiveness[order(effectiveness$Ranking),], type = 'multiBarChart')
n1$chart(stacked = TRUE)
n1$yAxis( tickFormat = "#!d3.format('%')!#" )
n1$set(width = 1000)
n1$xAxis(axisLabel = "Data available")
n1
```

The order remains 4 2 1 3

Thanks!

Comment: cool package. never used it so I can't say why this matters, but if you order by both data and ranking, it seems to work `effectiveness[with(effectiveness, order(data, Ranking)), ]`

Comment: it does! thanks a lot!